# Prevent snapback to original position in iScroll4

Tags: javascript

I'm using iScroll4 to make a certain element scrollable in my webpage but it snaps back to the original position once you release the mouse/touch. How do I make it stay instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have figured out why this happens. I had iscroll4 working in a Phonegap app that I was building, and then broke it after changing some CSS. At the time, I didn't realize what I had done and I spent a long time hunting for a Javascript solution.

Finally, I noticed that when I tested it in a browser, there was a scrollbar for the list where I was using iscroll4. And when I tried to scroll, the scrollbar thumb changed size. That is why it was snapping back. The browser made the wrapper div big enough to hold the entire list, so whenever I tried to scroll, there was no hidden data so I triggered the pull-up event and then the browser resized the div.

I had to change the CSS to include `overflow:hidden` and it started to work again. I tried `overflow:hidden` on the `ul` tag and the `scroller` div but that didn't work. It has to be on the `wrapper` div.